# Export image information via SQL

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql

I'm trying to export a set of image information from Magento 1.9 via SQL. I'm trying to get an output format like this:

```
sku, value, position
1234, a/b/example.jpg, 2
```

Tables involved:

- `catalog_product_entity` (sku)
- `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` (value)
- `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` (position)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run following query

```
SELECT cpe.sku, cpemg.value, cpemgv.position  FROM catalog_product_entity as cpe left join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery as cpemg on cpe.entity_id = cpemg.entity_id left join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value as cpemgv on cpemg.value_id = cpemgv.value_id
```